# Mail client on iPad

Tags: ipad, email, gmail

I wanted to create a mail client on the iPad. It need not require to support all mail accounts, only Gmail will do (but of course a complete mail client is always good).

But I am not getting how to go about it, any libraries for it?

I don't only want to send mails; I want to read them as well so I can't use *MFComposeMailViewController*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open-source projects:
http://code.google.com/p/skpsmtpmessage/
http://code.google.com/p/remail-iphone/
https://bitbucket.org/mronge/mailcore/

If you only need previews of the unread messages, simply use the GMail RSS feed.

Comment: Hey I have also came across libetpan which is a full fledged cocoa library but can be buit for iphone as well.